# Symfony along with NLTK

Tags: symfony

I have a script in Python that imports out of some other packages, the NLTK package.

The OS is Debian Stretch. Executing it directly on Linux everything works as should it be. But running the mentioned script with Sympony - Process, it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/var/www/html/public/_import.py\", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'
```

If simply I just comment "**import nltk**", all the script works properly even with Symfony Process at all.

Comment: What happens if you run the python script directly? Will it also complain about the missing import? Are there any installation instructions for the script, e.g. any mentions of installing dependencies via pip, virtualenv or source in the README?

Comment: @dbrumann as stated above, the answer is no: running directly there is no complain to by the system - Linux Debian Stretch. About dependencies, the second part of your comment, no. If I use php "exec", everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I could not leave this problem, as I have resolved it, without an answer for you that might be facing the same issue!

The problem at all was **not** caused by **Symfony - Process**, but, unfortunatly, by instalation behavior of the module named: "NLTK";

In my case, the user used to install things on Linux Debian Stretch was the **root**.

Try (now, you, before changes and check...) to use the following command in your terminal: `pip show nltk`.

The output is:

```
Name: nltk
Version: 3.4.5
Summary: Natural Language Toolkit
Home-page: http://nltk.org/
Author: Steven Bird
Author-email: stevenbird1@gmail.com
License: Apache License, Version 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: six
Required-by:
```

Take a look at **Location**. Now it is the right place. But, as default, `pip install nltk` will place it, in my case with user "root" installing things, at "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk" as the base path! So, when the user "www-data" tried to runing it... **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'**

> No module named 'nltk' - because it was not there to the place should it be accessed!

So, as you might guess now, **the problem as caused by permission issues**! Unfortunatly, no error (logs) output happened that would drive me to mind that would it be related to permission issues!

**The solution**:

1) Not messing around with the system or executing unecessary changes was considered at first place;

2) Had uninstalled it with pip the  module NLTK and I have seeked to find where the other modules were installed;

3) Installed it (NLTK) again, but now, placing it where I want, I mean, where it should be since the begening: among the others modules - as numpy -, that could be accessed easily and without issues!

> The command used was: 
>   **pip install --target="/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages"**
>   **--upgrade nltk**

Now, NLTK resides at **/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages** followed by all the other modules working properly like a charm!

I hope this helps you!